# Capture mouse movement and save as a picture

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Im creating a simple Pygame and I need to track mouse movement.

If I record mouse movement with mouse module. Is it possible to save how the mouse was moved as a picture? Or atleast save as a video?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no support for this. But I have one hack to do this.
1. Record mouse movement with [PyUserInput](https://pypi.org/project/PyUserInput/).

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
m = PyMouse()
x,y = m.position()
```

2. Than use pillow make image using cordinates

   from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
   img = Image.new((mode = "RGB", size = (200, 200)))
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
   draw.point((x, y), 'red')
   img.save('1.png')
3. Than you can use ffmpeg to concat video

And also you can use draw line to so for that you don't need ffmpeg. For that you have to store mouse position.

Comment: I tried using your solution but all the pictures are just black squares. And also how can I concat the a video from all these pictures?

Comment: for draw point you can also change size of pointer with pixels and for concat video you can use https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md#assemble-video-from-sequence-of-frames..